# Can an ethernet router affect the line attenuation of a VDSL2 connection?

Tags: router, internet, modem, vdsl

I have had issues with my U-Verse connection for the past 4 days. I was told to just use the modem. The numbers regarding it which are shown on the Broadband Status have lowered somewhat after I did that (which was earlier today). There was a bad storm recently which eventually caused the power to go out. Could that or the router being 2+ years old be the reason why the Internet was slow?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The VDSL2 modem is responsible for the analog to digital conversion.  Any ethernet router behind it is only dealing with the digital signals, so it can't affect the line attenuation.  (Also, its not connected to the line).

It is possible that the modem is performing worse then when it was new - that is a thing on cheaper modems.   That said, **it is a LOT more likely that the problem relates to the effects of the storm on the line.    Water can significantly change the characteristics of the copper and can cause degradation.**

If you are talking about say less then 10% difference before and after the restart, maybe wait a few days, check the attenuation again and if it has not improved try restarting the modem to get it to retrain.  If its more then 25%, chances are you will want to jump up and down and demand the connection be looked at by the Telco.

(*That is what I have done/would do in NZ.  YMMV with your telco**)

Comment: The Line Attenuation of the modem before I unplugged both routers were 61.9 (Downstream) and 54.4 (Upstream) for Line 1 and 61.9 (Downstream) and 54.8 (Upstream) for Line 2. After unplugging them, the Line Attenuation of the modem became 48.5 (Downstream) and 55.3 (Upstream) for Line 1 and 48.7 (Downstream) and 55.9 (Upstream) for Line 2.

Comment: What equipment are you using?  How is it configured?  Do you have bonded DSL?   What happens if you plug your routers back in ?

Comment: Just a BGW-210 and some Powerline Adapters at the moment. I think so. The issue has and is happening again even after unplugging the routers. The tech and higher ups tell us that the "line is fine" and that it is caused by "something that we are using".

Comment: Your question has become unclear.  If you remove the router and the problem persists then you have confirmed what I said in the post, which is the answer to your question.  I've not played round with this setup much, but it is plausible that Powerline adaptors can interfere with VDSL (and there is lots of evidence to support this online).   I'd rule out the powerline adaptors first, and if they are the cause of the problem, then look into if and how you can fix this (maybe a PSU with better filtering, maybe running cables differently)...

Comment: That said, if everything worked fine, then storm, then things work less fine (and you didn't change anything), you are being BS'd by the techs.  It may be that the line is still within what they consider OK, even though you are getting poorer performance.  AT&T are not exact;y renowned for their awesome customer satisfaction.

Comment: I unplugged the powerline adapters. The values are the same as when the routers and adapters were plugged in.

Comment: That does not surprise me.  That said, did you reboot the router after unplugging the adaptors?

Comment: The modem was plugged into the powerline adapter. So, it was reset when I unplugged it from the adapter and plugged it into the wall outlet.

Comment: Were there any other powerline adapters turned on after you removed the one connected to your router?   I'm suggesting here that the signal may be being generated by other powerline adaptors and may be reaching your modem through its power supply.  (Again, I think this is less likely then a problem with your line)

Comment: There's just the one in my room and the one upstairs. I will remove the one in my room and see if it helps. I will still have my mother contact them again sometime early in the day.

Comment: Your last comment changes things a bit.  Apologies (I'm an old person, and I have dealt with Telcos for a living), but quite simply the telco is taking advantage of the fact that your mother does not understand exactly what is happening...

Comment: What I would do is this.  (temporarily) disconnect all the powerline devices phones (and any splitters that are on the phones.   See if that improves performance.  If not, take a screenshot of the VDSL sync speeds and ask your mother to tell them that you have consulted with an expert (I am an expert), have performed the relevant tests (the isolation test above) and the failure is within the telco network.   If they don't want to send someone out, try get her to escalate with a supervisor and not take no for an answer.

Comment: I replaced the modem with the new one the technician left behind. I am now having stable Internet even though the numbers haven't changed much.

Comment: Never mind, the Broadband Connection went down just recently.

Comment: Could the wires in the box outside the house have gone bad?

Comment: They could have gotten wet, so yes, but they could have gotten wet at any join. If you have isolated the connection (no powerline, no other devices plugged in to phone jacks)  and teplace the router the problem is outside your control - save one other thing... Do you have a "land line" and if so, how is it connectrd?  Its possible you have a master splutter +filter) in the wall thats gone faulty.

Comment: Yes, we have phone service via U-Verse. The cordless phone base is connected via a phone jack in the kitchen which connects to a phone jack in the basement which the telephone cord from the modem is plugged into.

Comment: FEC Errors Line 2 is almost 80,000 under Downstream and is almost 14,000 under Upstream.

Comment: Do you have a VDSL filter on each phone?     What happens if you unplug all the phones (and any splitters they are on)?

Comment: The phone isn't plugged into a filter.